# threejs: Move camera to position inside another object

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to move the camera controlled by `trackballControl` into the position of an object.

Right now it's working but as you can see in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91xpg2La/8/), each time the camera changes position it also changes the `z` which isn't what I want.

I'm trying to keep the same `position` but only `rotate` the globe into the position of the `cube`.

Here is my code so far

```
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, cubeMesh;

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    camera.position.copy(cubeMesh.position);
    camera.lookAt(controls.target);
};

var initLights = function () {

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(light);
};

var init = function () {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 2;

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);
    var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xfb3550,
        flatShading: true
    });
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, sphereMat);

    //cube
    var cubeDim = 20;
    var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeDim, cubeDim, cubeDim);
    var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x7cf93e,
        flatShading: true
    });
    cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, cubeMat);


    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    spherical.set(100 + cubeDim / 2, 0.4, 0);
    cubeMesh.position.setFromSpherical(spherical);

    var zero = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    cubeMesh.lookAt(zero);


    scene.add(sphereMesh);
    sphereMesh.add(cubeMesh);

    initLights();
};

var render = function () {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
};


init();
animate()
```

You can test it in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91xpg2La/8/) here

Comment: If you run the fiddle, the `z` is no longer the same after clicking the button. The camera goes at the position but change the `z`. What i want to do is only rotate the sphere so it goes to the cube position

Comment: Your approach with `camera.position.copy(cubeMesh.position);` is correct, you just didin't finish it ) So the line should be like this: `camera.position.copy(cubeMesh.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(300);`, where `300` is the distance between positions of the camera and sphere.

Comment: Thanks you so much exactly what I wanted. Do you have any links or something to understand better the normalize and multiplyscalar

Comment: You can find all that stuff in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle where the camera is zoomed a little bit out by clicking the button.
[JS  Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91xpg2La/10/)

```
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, cubeMesh;

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
        let x = cubeMesh.position.x
    let y = cubeMesh.position.y
    let z = cubeMesh.position.z
    camera.position.x = 0
    camera.position.y = y + 200
    camera.position.z = z + 100
    camera.lookAt(controls.target);
};

var initLights = function () {

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(light);
};

var init = function () {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 2;

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);
    var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xfb3550,
        flatShading: true
    });
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, sphereMat);

    //cube
    var cubeDim = 20;
    var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeDim, cubeDim, cubeDim);
    var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x7cf93e,
        flatShading: true
    });
    cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, cubeMat);


    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    spherical.set(100 + cubeDim / 2, 0.4, 0);
    cubeMesh.position.setFromSpherical(spherical);

    var zero = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    cubeMesh.lookAt(zero);


    scene.add(sphereMesh);
    sphereMesh.add(cubeMesh);

    initLights();
};

var render = function () {
        console.log(camera.position)
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
};


init();
animate()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you specifically add these values (in on click method)

Comment: i have tried it out. I think you can calculate the vector with the same zoom but i dont know how...

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. I'm gonna try to find exactly the reason. Tell me if you find anything

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the camera target to the position where you want to look at.

```
var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
newTarget.copy(cubeMesh.position);
camera.lookAt(newTarget);
```

and the `THREE.TrackballControls` has to be notified to update from the camera `THREE.TrackballControls.update`:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newTarget.copy(cubeMesh.position);
    controls.reset();
    camera.lookAt(newTarget)
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.update();
};
```

If the current camera position should be kept and not be reseted, then the position has to be read form the world matrix of the camera and the initial position of the camera has to be set to its current position:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () 
    var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newPosition.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
    var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newTarget.copy(cubeMesh.position);
    controls.reset();
    camera.position.copy(newPosition);
    camera.lookAt(newTarget)
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.update();
};
```

See the example:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, cubeMesh;

document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function () {
    var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newTarget.copy(cubeMesh.position);
    controls.reset();
    camera.lookAt(newTarget)
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.update();
};

document.getElementById('target').onclick = function () {
    var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newPosition.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
    var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    newTarget.copy(cubeMesh.position);
    controls.reset();
    camera.position.copy(newPosition);
    camera.lookAt(newTarget)
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.update();
};


var initLights = function () {

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(light);
};

var init = function () {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 2;

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);
    var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xfb3550,
        flatShading: true
    });
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, sphereMat);

    //cube
    var cubeDim = 20;
    var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeDim, cubeDim, cubeDim);
    var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x7cf93e,
        flatShading: true
    });
    cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, cubeMat);


    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    spherical.set(100 + cubeDim / 2, 0.4, 0);
    cubeMesh.position.setFromSpherical(spherical);

    var zero = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    cubeMesh.lookAt(zero);


    scene.add(sphereMesh);
    sphereMesh.add(cubeMesh);

    initLights();
};

var render = function () {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
};


init();
animate();
```

```css
button {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    right : 0;
}

.button2  {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

<button id="reset" class="button2">
    reset camera
</button>

<button id="target">
    look at target
</button>
```

Comment: I tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/91xpg2La/11/) but it only reset the initial position but never lookat the object. Tell me if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @zaarr78 You have to use the 2nd variant of the `onclick` event from the answer - see the code snippet